# Bouncy Castle RSA keypair generation using Lightweight API

Tags: java, security, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

Surprisingly enough there's very little information on the Web about using Bouncy Castle's lightweight API. After looking around for a while I was able to put together a basic example:

```
RSAKeyPairGenerator generator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
generator.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters
    (
        new BigInteger("10001", 16),//publicExponent
        SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"),//prng
        1024,//strength
        80//certainty
    ));

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

I have a basic understanding of RSA and the math that happens behind the scenes, so I understand what `publicExponent` and `strength` are. I presume `publicExponent` refers to a coprime of `phi(pq)` and from what I gather it can be small (like 3) as long as appropriate padding is used. However, I have no idea what `certainty` refers to (some place mentioned that it might refer to a percentage but I want to be sure). The use of `SecureRandom` is self-explanatory. The [documentation of RSAKeyGenerationParameters](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/index.html) is completely worthless (no surprise there). My only guess is that it has something to do with the accuracy of the generated keys, but again I want to be sure. So my question is what are appropriate values for `certainty` and `publicExponent`?

P.S.
Please don't reply with "it depends on the context - how secure you want the information to be". It's pretty safe to assume highest degree of security (i.e. 4096-bit RSA key or greater) unless otherwise specified... I would also appreciate links to sources that give good example of the use of Bouncy Castle's Lightweight API (I'm not at all interested in the JCA implementation or any examples pertaining to it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using correct values for both.

The publicExponent should be a [Fermat Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). 0x10001 (F4) is current recommended value. 3 (F1) is known to be safe also.

The RSA key generation requires prime numbers. However, it's impossible to generate absolute prime numbers. Like any other crypto libraries, BC uses probable prime numbers. The certainty indicate how certain you want the number to be prime. Anything above 80 will slow down key generation considerably.

Please note that RSA algorithm still works in the unlikely event that the prime number is not true prime because BC checks for relative primeness.

Comment: Given that the point of the 'probable prime' is that you can't factor it, how can you check if its relatively prime to another number?  Isn't the relative primeness check just another probabilistic check?

Comment: Relative primeness can be checked easily by calculating GCD. If it's 1, 2 numbers are relative prime.

Comment: It is *not* impossible to generate provably prime integers, but it is more expensive and considered unnecessary for RSA. Ueli Maurer gave a fast algorithm for this many years ago.

Comment: Also, are you sure the algorithm still works in case a non-prime 'prime' is generated? I've not checked it myself. BC checks for relative primeness to (p-1)(q-1), but if, say, p is not prime then (p-1)(q-1) is not the correct value for phi(n), so the math breaks down.

Comment: Running RSA is a kind of convoluted probalistic primality testing on the involved numbers. If p is non-prime then RSA will fail on many inputs -- but we are talking about a p which just passed a test designed to make non-prime fail with high probability.

Answer (score 9):

I'd have to delve into their source code to be "certain", but I believe that the `certainty` parameter is passed straight to the [`BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Random%29) constructor, which says, "The probability that the new `BigInteger` represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 1/2<sup>certainty</sup>). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter."

So, with a value of 80, there is less than 1 chance in 2<sup>80</sup> that the number will not be prime. The comment suggests that the prime number generation time is linear with respect to this parameter, but you should test that to be sure if you choose to increase it. It might make sense to use a value that is consistent with the key size you are using. For example, NIST says that a 1024-bit RSA key is as strong as an 80-bit symmetric key. For a 2048-bit RSA key, you might want to use a certainty of 112 bits (the equivalent strength symmetric key size), and so on.

It sounds like you are aware of the vulnerability of using 3 as the public exponent in special cases. The value 65537 is used almost universally now.

Comment: The "vulnerabilities" of 3 as public exponent are mostly a big, historical misunderstanding. 65537 is a prime example of cargo cult in computer science. 65537 is not bad, but 3 is not worse either; if 3 leads to weaknesses then you are doing something else wrong, and using 65537 instead would probably not save you.

Comment: @Thomas: In regard to setting the value of the public exponent to 65537, I suspected as much. It could also be greater then 65537, right? Any prime will do?

Comment: @yamsha: the public exponent can be any value which is _relatively prime_ to p-1 and q-1 (where p and q are the prime factors of the RSA modulus). The RSA key generator uses the provided public exponent as parameter, and selects appropriate p and q. This rules out even values. Any odd integer (except 1) can be used as public exponent; using a prime only makes it slightly simpler for the key generator. The cost of public key operations raises with the size of the public exponent, so you probably want to keep it small.

Comment: @yamsha: also, some widely deployed RSA implementations have trouble with large public exponent. For instance, the standard RSA implementation in Windows (used when Internet Explorer connects to a HTTPS Web site) does not tolerate public exponents which do not fit in a 32-bit unsigned integer. Using e=3 or e=65537 works "everywhere".

Answer (score 3):

A good reference is [FIPS PUB 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf). In particular, appendix B section 3 has many security parameters, as well as prime generation algorithms.`certainty` is the number of iterations of the Miller-Rabin primality test.

Answer (score 2):

[See this answer on crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3114/371) for more information on how your value of certainty should be calculated.

**Preview of Paŭlo Ebermann's answer:**

> Certainty of x bits means that the probability that something (in this
>   case p being prime) not being true is smaller than 2−x. This is the
>   same probability as guessing a random x-bit value correctly on the
>   first try, hence the name.
>
> How to select x? We want the probability of p (and q) not being prime
>   to be small enough that a failure probability in this point is not
>   larger than other ways the system could be broken - like guessing a
>   symmetric key, factoring the modulus etc.
>
> So here a correspondence table of symmetric and asymmetric key sizes
>   should help. http://www.keylength.com/ Pick the same prime certainty as you would pick an
>   symmetric key size accompanying your public key usage.